# How can I include NULLs in a PivotTable Count over SSAS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, ssas-2012

I have a view that joins orders to web tracking data which is being used as a fact table. I have lots of nulls because it takes a while for orders to obtain web tracking information. As you can see i have a total row count of 86432.  However my measure count is showing 52, 753 (simple row count when you build a measure group).  (Is using exactly the same view).  [image]

[image]

I believe my counts are going to be wrong due to the nulls in my data.  How can I get SSAS to correctly count my null values?  (I am limited to what I can do to the source database as I don't have access to change the core structure of the source system).

[image]

[image]

I understand what you are saying about counting a field vs all fields however as you can see by creating a new measure in SSAS you have the option of count of rows of a source table.  This is the behaviour I would expect and I would expect the same count as SELECT * on the table as shown in my images...

Comment: How about using a more appropriate field? If the `Order` field contains nulls, it's not the appropriate field to count whatever it is you want to count (customers perhaps?). Use your table's primary key instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's what it should be doing though?  It should just be counting the rows?  See image above... unless my understanding is wrong...

Comment: No it shouldn't. NULLs aren't items or orders. They are nothing at all. You wouldn't expect `NULL` to affect a SQL Count, why do you expect it to behave differently in SSAS? Anyway, why are you using this field to count the occurences of a different entity?

Comment: Usually people count the entire row, assuming the entire row isn't null, using COUNT(*) versus COUNT(someField) which could have a NULL and thus, wouldn't equal the ROWCOUNT. Or you could COUNT(COALESCE(YourField,1)) or something similar to handle the NULL

Comment: it is counting the entire row though isn't it??? if you look at the image from the measure... @scsimon

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you look at the image to my understanding it should be counting the ROW this is what SSAS creates by default when you create a measure group.  I don't understand why it's not doing that...

Comment: @jhowe that's wrong. If you ask for a *field's* count, NULLS are excluded both in SSAS and SQL (any standards-compliant database that is). If I asked for a count of orders in a 1000 row table with only a single non-null value, why should I get back anything other than 1?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't know if you're familiar with SSAS please see my last image.  This should be counting the ROW not an individual field... thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes I am. Since 1997. No XMLA or MDX, no schema - not possible to answer. I'm not asking for the screenshots, although what you posted shows the *usage* of the measure, not what function is used.

Comment: To put it another way - if such a fundamental thing was broken, people would have noticed in the last 19 years. On the other hand, the PivotTable's UI can sometimes confuse even experienced users. Cubes aren't tables either, and measures aren't rows.

Comment: Does DimAd have a null or zero AdKey row? I suspect that is your problem. When you process your cube do you have to adjust the error configuration settings so it doesn't error out? I am wondering if the null dimension key rows are being discarded during processing.

Comment: @greggalloway Hi Greg how are you long time no speak, correct me if I'm wrong I was reading another question if while slicing across the measure if the measure is joined to a dim (even if not selected in excel or cube browser) and there is a null key (no join) it will not count a complete row? I think this is my issue (and was unexpected as I was only selecting a measure and no dims) And yes I had to modify error processing to get the fact table to process. I just want the point confirmed if there is null field in a row does it not count the row in a measure group.

Comment: @jhowe during query time if you don't slice by a dimension it won't filter by it. But during processing time is when you are dropping the rows. So those rows don't even exist in the cube. I will write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe DimAd does not have a null or zero AdKey row. And I believe during processing you have to change the error configuration to have it discard or ignore any fact table rows where the foreign key is null.

My top recommendation is to change your fact table foreign keys to be not null. You will need to create a -1 key in each dimension and then use it in the fact table instead of null as described [here](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/5/16/usage-of-unknown-member-rows-in-a-data-warehouse.html).

If that's not feasible then add null or zero AdKey rows to any dimension where the fact table foreign key can be null. SSAS should convert the Bulls to zero so either should work. Then during processing those rows won't be dropped because they join fine. And you won't have to change the error configuration during processing.

If that's not feasible or acceptable then you can turn on the Unknown member on all dimensions which could be nullable. Then in the Dimension Usage tab set each relationship to fallback to the Unknown member. This process is described [here](https://onemanwenttomow.wordpress.com/2014/05/28/enabling-the-unknown-member-on-a-dimension-in-ssas/).

Answer (score -1):

In order to get a true row count you need not to count the column, but instead use *.

`COUNT(*)` will count all rows, regardless of `NULL`

`COUNT(Column)` counts only `NON-NULL` values

**Test Example**

```
declare @table table (i int)
insert into @table (i) values
(1),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)

select count(*) from @table --returns 4
select count(i) from @table --returns 1
```

Comment: this still doesn't explain why my measure says Source --> VWFactOrder (Row) and it is not counting the rows correctly...

Comment: You never posted either schema or query. This partial screenshot doesn't help at all. Where is the *field* definition? What was the query that was executed? We can't guess what your source and fields definition is. In any case, that comment is actually a question about the PivotTable UI, best answered by checking Excel's help - place the cursor in the property and hit F1.